# How to use atomic_bool properly

Tags: c, thread-safety, atomic, stdatomic

I'm not sure how to use the **atomic_bool** type from **stdatomic.h** in C. I'm able to find a lot of C++ examples but nothing regarding C.

A bit of context : I'm trying to have an atomic boolean to be able to stop the infinite loop of one of my threads.

The first thing I did was the following :

```c
#include <stdatomic.h>
static atomic_bool logger_thread_running = true;
```

And I loop like this :

```c
while(logger_thread_running)
```

When I want to stop my thread, I simply do :

```c
logger_thread_running = false;
```

It seems to work fine, but I need to be sure it's really atomic. I've seen on the internet some people initializing their bool like this :

```c
static atomic_bool logger_thread_running = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(true);
```

And using `atomic_store` and `atomic_load` to use the boolean. Should I use those instead or is it atomic already the way I did it ? And if it's not atomic already, why does gcc compile it without throwing any warning ? Thanks!

Edit : I don't want the overhead of a mutex here. I don't care if a few more loop iterations occur because the kernel's thread scheduling decided so.

Comment: Looks like it depends on the version, in `C17` it's not needed. https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2018/08/06/c17-obsoletes-atomic_var_init/

Comment: It was not needed in C11 mostly either.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2148.htm#dr_485

Comment: "No known implementations use embedded locks, however, and as such there is no technical requirement for the use of the ATOMIC_VAR_INIT macro."

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys ! Does that mean I should use ATOMIC_VAR_INIT if I want my code to be as portable as possible ? And what about atomic_(store|load) ? Should I use them ?

Comment: *Does that mean I should use `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT`* No, the requirement in ISO C that a default-initialized static atomic variable also needs to work pretty much precludes any design that would require a non-trivial `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT`.  TL:DR: ISO C was trying to allow more implementation options with this idea, but ended up not doing so, and now they're just removing the complexity because nothing ever requires it.

Comment: *And what about atomic_(store|load) ? Should I use them?*  No, only `atomic_store_explicit` or load is useful if you want a memory order weaker than seq_cst.  Otherwise simple assignment is equivalent to store, and reading the value (lvalue to rvalue conversion) is equivalent to load.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)